# How to access stdClass Multi level object or array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap, stdclass

I had to make a particularly complex SOAP request in PHP and seem to have received back objects within objects. I need to get a particular value for example "session_token". I can var_dump the request and even turn it in to an array but I can't access individual elements. Please help!

Objects:

```
stdClass Object ( [login_response] => stdClass Object 
    ( [response_context] => stdClass Object 
        ( [session_token] => b1043dcb82625701188ffff03572 
            [response_status] => OK [response_message] => Login successful 
                ))))
```

Converted array:

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [response_context] => 
        Array ( [session_token] => b1043dcb82625701188ffff03572 
            [response_status] => OK [response_message] => Login successful
             ) ) )
```

Comment: As an object `$obj->login_response->response_context->session_token` for example

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh why didn't you put that as an answer, it's so beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: Ok done as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave it as an object, and there is not reason not to.

```
echo $obj->login_response->response_context->session_token;
echo $obj->login_response->response_context->response_status;
echo $obj->login_response->response_context->response_message;
```

will output

```
b1043dcb82625701188ffff03572
OK
Login successful
```

Answer (score 2):

Once it's an array, it's JUST an array, e.g.

```
$obj->foo->bar->baz
```

will simply be

```
$arr['foo']['bar']['baz']
```

So in your case

```
$arr[0]['response_context']['response_status'] -> "OK"
```

Comment: Thanks, also a great answer

Answer (score 0):

Normally to access any key of an object, need to call it like this

```
echo $obj->key;
```

But, as this is a multi-level object, to access the element, you have to code like bellow.

```
echo $obj->login_response->response_context->session_token;
```

And the result will be `b1043dcb82625701188ffff03572`

As same, normally to access any key of an array, need to call it like this

```
echo $arr['key'];
```

But, as this is a multi-level array, to access the element, you have to code like bellow.

```
echo $arr[0]['response_context']['session_token'];
```

And the Output is `b1043dcb82625701188ffff03572`

Here,
`0` is the key of `$arr` array.

`response_context` is the key of `0`.

`session_token` is the key of `response_context`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this service, [array visualizer](http://array.include-once.org), this will help you target and extract only what you need. Just past the print_r output in it. That's it.
Give it a try

Comment: Making output pretty has NOTHING to do with with accessing it.

Comment: I agree that it makes it looks pretty but on the other hand it also shows the correct code to access a particular array item , hence it helps a newbie to visualise the structure of the array and also provides the code for each element.

Comment: When i started with the APIs , i faced the same problem, this tool helped me get what i need, hence i shared it.

Comment: Irrelevant. link-only answers are NOT answers.